# Unable to add library in main project with different flavoured library

Tags: android, gradle

I have an library module with two flavour and also my app module has two flavour, when i try to add my library module to my app module, it shows error says that it cannot find the library in the dependency.

**app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.local"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug{

        }
    }
    flavorDimensions("test")
    productFlavors {

        free {
            dimension "test"
            applicationId "com.example.local.free"
        }

        paid {
            dimension "test"
            applicationId "com.example.local.paid"
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    paidDebugImplementation
    paidReleaseImplementation
    freeDebugImplementation
    freeReleaseImplementation
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    paidDebugImplementation project(path : ':locallibs',configuration : 'f1Debug')
    freeDebugImplementation project(path : ':locallibs',configuration : 'f2Debug')
    paidReleaseImplementation project(path : ':locallibs',configuration : 'f1Release')
    freeReleaseImplementation project(path : ':locallibs',configuration : 'f2Release')

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

}
```

Here is my library gradle
**locallibs.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug{

        }
    }
    defaultPublishConfig "f1Debug"

    flavorDimensions("default")
    productFlavors{
        f1{
            dimension "default"
        }

        f2{
            dimension "default"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
}
```

This is the error am getting

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@paidDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :locallibs.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@paidDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :locallibs.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@paidDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :locallibs.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@paidRelease/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :locallibs.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@paidReleaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :locallibs.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@freeDebug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :locallibs.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@freeDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :locallibs.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@freeDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :locallibs.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@freeRelease/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :locallibs.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@freeReleaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :locallibs.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

Can anyone help me out with this ?